# Need to click confirmButton twice with Jetpack compose's AlertDialog with OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using jetpack compose's [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog) with a textfield inside. The idea is that the user should fill in some text in the text field and click confirm. The problem is, after inserting text into the `OutlinedTextField`, one needs to click the `confirmButton` twice - once for removing focus from the `OutlinedTextField` (to remove the soft keyboard) and once for actually clicking the confirm button.

Not completely sure if this behavior could be intentional. However, with the "normal" AlertDialog, this is not the case.

Here's a minimal code example:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    private fun MyAlertDialog() {
        val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        val hasConfirmed = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        if (!hasConfirmed.value) {
            AlertDialog(
                title = { Text("Title") },
                text = {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = text.value,
                        onValueChange = {
                            text.value = it
                        },
                        label = {
                            ProvideEmphasis(emphasis = EmphasisAmbient.current.medium) {
                                Text(
                                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.notes),
                                    style = typography.body2
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                },
                onDismissRequest = {
                },
                confirmButton = {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        hasConfirmed.value = true
                    },
                    ) {
                        Text("Confirm")
                    }
                }
            )
        } else {
            Text("Confirmed")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems to work on Api 30; but it does require two clicks on Api 27, 28, 29 (only tested on emulators with Api 27, 28, 29 and 30)

Comment: there are currently multiple issues with TextFields and their focus inside Dialogs. You might want to look into the issue tracker and add yours if it does not exist yet.

Comment: Currently works for me with 1 click. Compose version: 1.0.3. Tested in device with API 24.